# How to SOLVE system errors at startup, not just report them

Tags: 14.04, startup, bug-reporting

When I start my new Ubuntu system running on Lenovo Thinkpad T540P, I always get two or three popups mentioning some System problem and giving me the opportunity to report them.  Aside from waiting for some good soul at Ubuntu to tell me what is going on, which I do not expect to happen, what can I do to see exactly what the system is complaining about, so that I might possibly have a shot at correcting it myself.  Is it possible for example, for me to see the reports the system is filing on my behalf?  Or is there a log that will point me to the problem?

Other than the fact that these things pop up, I see nothing wrong with the system.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it following the directions given by stevecoh1 above. Go to the Terminal and type: sudo rm /var/crash/*
Thank you very much stevecoh1.

Answer (score 12):

I have the same problem, and I think its a bug on the Ubuntu error reporting system (which is called "apport"). Apport notifies the problem to Ubuntu developers, in view of having it solved by them in the next Ubuntu update or release.

Unfortunately seems that in the last Ubuntu releases, some error reports are not registered as submitted, so the system loops the task every time the computer starts up.

Go to the Terminal and type:

> sudo rm /var/crash/*

That will manually delete all the old crashes in stored memory, and you'll stop receive these notifications. Until a new report will loop again though...